# Logstash: No emails received from logstash for email output plugin

Tags: logstash

I do not get any emails from logstash for the below config. Could anyone please help me what is going wrong, also please let me know where can I trace the email logs. There is no any error on running the the config file.

The output part of config file is as below:

```
output {
    elasticsearch { 
            embedded => true 
                }   

if ("INFO" in [message])  {
  email {
           subject => "logstash alert"
           to => "xyz@abc.co.in"
           via => "sendmail"
           body => "Here is the event line that occured: %{message}"
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please show the message you're testing with. To isolate the moving pieces, wrap the conditional around a regular `stdout {}` output and ignore the email output for now.

Comment: I do get the output through ES and kibana. But unable to get the emails for the same. Please find below the filter applied for the config file: filter {
  if ("INFO" in [message]){
    mutate {
    add_field => [ "level", "INFO" ]
     }
   }

Comment: Sure, but I do suggest you ignore the email output for now and make sure you get messages sent to a stdout output first. If that works it's a strong indication that the problem is with the email output. If it doesn't work, things go wrong even earlier.

Comment: Hi Magnus, I do get the output through stdout.

Comment: Even when stdout is wrapped inside the conditional? If so we know it's the email output. Look in your mail log (/var/log/mail.info or similar) for clues.

Answer (score 1):

The `in` operator checks for an array that contains a value.  In your case, that won't work because it looks like you are expecting a raw log line to match.  What you want is:

```
if [message] =~ /INFO/ {
}
```

Comment: No emails even after changing the conditionals.